# Ignite client mvn artifact's purpose?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I notice there is a maven artifact with artifact id "ignite-clients". Any one knows what its purpose is?

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ignite/ignite-clients/2.4.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's basically an empty JAR since `ignite-clients` only contains tests now. I'll raise this issue on developers mailing list.

Comment: Thanks @alamar for the clarification!